# Reading AppSetting.json Settings in another project from same solution in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is my appsetting.json file Reading AppSettings.json file please understand my Solution Structure

```
  ElasticCoreWebApi              //.net Core Web Application 3.1
    -> AppSettings.json
  ElasticCoreWebApi.Utility
    ->CommonObject.cs            //.net Console Application
```

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "elasticsearch": {
    "AcqIndex": "MyIndex",
    "AcqDataUrl": "MyUrl",
    "AcqNodeId": "MyUser",
    "AcqNodePwd": "MyPassword"
  },
  "MySettings": {
    "Parameters": {
      "LogsPath": "E:\\Logs\\",
      "LogDir": "LogAsad",
      "ErrorLogDir": "ErrorLog",
      "ServiceLogDir": "ServiceLog",
      "UserName": "username123",
      "Password": "password123",
      "TripleDesKey": "MyDESKey",
      "LogType": "FILE",
      "LogConnectionString": "LogConnectionString",
      "LogTable": "LOGGER",
      "LogDirectory": "C:\\Logs\\asad.NiSolution.pk\\",
      "MaxNoOfLinesInLogFile": "50000",
      "LogLevel": "Error,SystemTrace,FunctionTrace,Information",
      "ERPName": "erp123",
      "ERPPassword": "erp@321!"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my CommonObject.cs Class file in ElasticCoreWebApi.Utility  what i am trying to do is Reading AppSetting.json MySettings all things just like what i was doing from Asp.net WebForm WebConfig file which was written in XML in app-setting Tag

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
//using WSUtil = WS.Core.Util;

namespace ElasticCoreWebApi.Utility
{
    public class CommonObjects
    {

        #region Configuration
        public static string GetCongifValue(string ConfigKey)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigKey].ToString();
        }

        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            //return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GenericConstants.ConnectionStringKey].ConnectionString;
            return ((new WSUtil.TripleDES()).Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GenericConstants.ConnectionStringKey].ConnectionString));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help.
There is a nuget package called "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json".
I believe that code is part of asp.net, but it can be added as a nuget package to a .net core project.

Some sample code:

```
// using ...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ElasticCoreWebApi.Utility
{
    public class Settings
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;

        public Settings()
        {
            // Ensure that files exists
            // You may want to add some default settings in case it is missing

            _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(/*File path goes here*/).Build();
        }

        
        public T Get<T>(string section, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_config.GetSection(section)[key], typeof(T));
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.Message);
                return default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some adjustments might be needed to cover things like child dictionary but it might be a place to start.

Comment: What will go in AddjsonFile()   my appsettings.json file which is in ElasticCoreWebApi Project